# Saving multithreaded game

Tags: java, multithreading, save

I have written a 2d platformer in java, and i was wondering how i would save the game.  I looked at just serializing the whole game using XMLEncoder or ObjectOutputStream, however those didn't save threads correctly.  When i started the game again the thread weren't running.  So then i tried calling start on all of the threads after the game loaded, but that created a major problem with the threads being in invalid states and the game started glitching up.  What is the best way to just write the whole game to a save file.

Comment: Would it be possible to save the state of your threads and later create a new thread, set its state to the stuff you saved and then start it? Hard do give a good advice without a bit of code or even a hint what the problems are

Comment: Well it would be hard to post the code since it is 1000s of lines, but if i created a new thread it wouldn't be in the same part of its execution if i then created a new thread.

Comment: could you work with thread groups or keep track of and save all dependencies between your different threads?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Saving a game will rarely be as straightforward as saving all objects exactly as they are in memory at the time of exit/saving and then loading them back to their exact state afterward.

It is more likely that you will need/want to create a data structure to represent your game's state which you will then write to disk.  Multithreading is unlikely to be your primary concern.  You will want to start these threads back up anew when you load your game state.

Consider that many games save/load via a menu.  If your game starts out with a splash screen, or at least a main menu, you wouldn't want to be loading objects from their exact state on startup anyway.  Find the minimal important elements that you **need** to reconstruct everything that is important about the state of the game and save that to disk.  Most of the state of a game can be implicitly recreated from a very small amount of data.

Sadly, the exact method of how you should save/load your game is not easily answered on a Q/A website as it will depend heavily on the exact data structures you are using and the entire nature of your game.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't be of more help; there really isn't a short one-size-fits all solution to your problem.

Answer (score 2):

You should serialize only your business domain data, not threads.  Threads need to be created again when you reload data.  ObjectOutputStream is ok assuming your domain classes are Serializable.